# Empty Dashboard Issue with Harviacode CRUD Generator in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am encountering an issue while attempting to open the dashboard for the Harviacode CRUD Generator in CodeIgniter 3. When I try to access the CRUD generator dashboard, it only displays a blank page without any error messages. I'm using CodeIgniter 3 framework on XAMPP with Windows 10 operating system.

I have followed the installation instructions for the Harviacode CRUD Generator in CodeIgniter 3 and configured everything accordingly. However, upon navigating to the CRUD generator dashboard, the page appears empty without any content or error message.

Here are some details regarding my setup:

CodeIgniter version: 3
PHP version: 8.0.13
XAMPP version: 3.3.0
Windows 10 OS

Clearing the browser cache and cookies.
Checking the error logs in XAMPP, but no relevant error messages were found.
Ensuring that all necessary files and configurations are in place as per the installation guide.
Could someone provide insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue? Are there any specific configurations or additional steps I might have missed during the setup process?

Any help or guidance to resolve this problem with the Harviacode CRUD Generator dashboard not displaying content would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.